# How to use same control between two forms in Visual Basic 6?

Tags: .net, winforms, vb6

I have two forms and need to share text controls between two forms, such that if I enter a value in the textbox in Form-A, it should update the same value in the textbox in Form-B.

Is it possible? If yes, can you please explain how I can implement it into my project, since I'm a newbie to Visual Basic 6.0.

I tried creating a control array, but that didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  In the .Change event of the textbox on formA, enter the following code:

```
FormB.TextboxB.Text=Me.TextboxA.Text
```

Where FormB is the name of form B, TextboxB is the name of the textbox on form B, FormA is the name of form A, TextboxA is the name of the textbox on form A.

Comment: I get two errors 1) While running "**Method or Data member not found**" and when I stop I get "**UNABLE TO BIND TO FIELD OR DATAMEMBER:'ADDRESS'**"

Comment: The "method or data member not found" is because the name of a form or control does not match the name that you are using in the code.  The "UNABLE TO BIND TO FIELD OR DATAMEMBER:'ADDRESS'" is not related to this.  This is because of something that you are doing wrong with accessing data from a database.